# How can I fix this behavior of getMethod()?

Tags: java

In class *A*, i got a function called `updateAttribute`. In class *B*, I got a *junit* test, which stores during execution this function in a *Method* *object* (code is simplified).

```
public class A {
    public Optional<AttributeObject> updateAttribute(
        @ApiParam("Qual of attribute") @PathParam("qual") @Qual final String qual,
        @NotNull @Valid final UpdateObject a) {

        // here, I've cut a few lines of code

        return null;
    }
}
```

---

```
public class ATest extends AnotherTest {

    @Test
    public void someTest()
            throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
        try (
            // some code I've cut

            final Method method =
                A.getClass().getMethod("updateAttribute", String.class, UpdateObject.class);

            // some code I've cut
        }
    }
}
```

---

The junit test fails at this call of .getMethod() with:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HV000181: Wrong number of
>   parameters. Method or constructor
>   java.util.Optional"<"packageName.A">"#updateAttribute(String,
>   UpdateObject) expects 1 parameters, but got 2.
>   (...)

When I change the call to

```
        final Method method =
            A.getClass().getMethod("updateAttribute", String.class);
```

or similar, the trace just claims - as expected - that this method doesn't exist.
Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Use @ApiParam for the second parameter also

Comment: @GhostCat I've read it and I think I followed those instructions intuitively already. I changed names, cutted unnecessary code / trace etc.. and also I think, I've made clear which error appears and which line of code causes this error.

Comment: @MangduYogii hmm, I've tried it. The same error appears :/

Comment: I get a compiler error for A.getClass() (non static method from static context) ... because that should say A.class. And having it as resource for a TRY statement is plain wrong too. So sorry: I have no idea what you are doing, but what you are showing to us is **not** something you can base a question on. So again: read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Sending us code that doesn't even compile: no go.

Comment: It looks to me that you are calling `.getMethod()` on a wrong object. If you look closely at the exception message you can see that it tried to access the `updateAttribute()` method of `java.util.Optional`

Comment: @Amongalen thanks for noticing. I didn't notice, that stackoverflow masked a part which was enclosed in "<...>". I couldn't find out how to mask them ordinary which is why I just put them in quotation marks.

Comment: Yet still, it looks like you're calling `.getMethod()` on a `java.util.Optional<packageName.A>` which obviously doesn't have `updateAttribute()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, just content that doesn't fit into a comment.

Reduced the code to this:

```
   @Test
    public void someTest()
            throws NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
                final Method method =
                            A.class.getMethod("updateAttribute", String.class, Integer.class);
        }
}

class A {
    public Optional<String> updateAttribute(
            final String qual, Integer a) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And that works fine.

Not reproducable.